# Guidance using Susy One Breakpoint Output

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass, susy-sass

I am using odbird's susy framework and have set my large desktop media query to have a class which is writing out the larges breakpoint with the class "lt-ie9" prepended as I am using H5BP.

The problem I have been having is setting the Breakpoint Output variables i.e. $breakpoint-media-output.

What I want to achieve ideally is either in my single style sheet hiding the smaller breakpoints from IE or to create a separate IE sheet with only ie code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Smaller breakpoints will be hidden from older versions of IE if they are inside a media-query. That doesn't require any help from Susy - browsers that don't support media-queries will ignore all their contents. If you do want to set up a special IE stylesheet, you have a few options. It's easiest if you have all your code in partials, then import those partials into your various output files. Set these variables before you import the partials in each output file.

To output the code for modern browsers:

```
$breakpoint-media-output: true;
$breakpoint-ie-output: false;
```

To output the code for IE:

```
$breakpoint-media-output: false;
$breakpoint-ie-output: true;
```